# Request Datas from 2 sites in bootstrap Datatable

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap datatable-basic with a few pages.
In the first cell of the table is a checkbox.

The table looks like that just with a few more rows.

```
<table class="table datatable-basic table-hover" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Keyword</th>
        <th>Suchvolumen</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxManuellerStatus1" name="checkboxManuellerStatus[1]"  value="abc"> abc</td>          
        <td class="keywordDataStyle">abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxManuellerStatus2" name="checkboxManuellerStatus[2]"  value="abc2"> abc</td>         
        <td class="keywordDataStyle">abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

All checkboxes have incrementing names and ids. checkboxManuellerStatus1,checkboxManuellerStatus2,checkboxManuellerStatus3,... and so on.

If I request the checkboxes in php, I get all the values of checked checkboxes.

```
$array = $_REQUEST['checkboxManuellerStatus'];
```

Thats good, except that I only get the values of the current page in the table, but I need all values of all pages. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: but I need all values of all pages What do mean by this ? Is the name is same in all pages for checkbox ?

Comment: Yes, i have 50 rows in that table, all names/ids are up to checkboxManuellerStatus50. The page size is 10. So i have 5 pages a 10 rows. If I request the table, I only get the 10 checkboxes of the current page. If im on page 2, I only get checkbox10 to checkbox20. But I need all of the table

Comment: you can do this by using cookie or session ...

Comment: @Introser you can do this by setting cookie OR just click on next page button just store current page checkbox value till u reach 5. In last append all values and send. You can store in a local variable also. But u gonna lost on refresh page.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I thought there is maybe a default way to request all easy, so I dont have to store it manually somewhere else.